# How to extract a substring from the result of a WMI query in batch?

Tags: batch-file, substring, extract, wmi

I have some WMI batch queries, this one gets the computer's (mostely laptops) processor information :

```
rem proc. info
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('wmic cpu get Name^ /format:csv') do (
    set PRCNAM=%%a 
rem && echo !PRCNAM!| findstr /r /c:"!PRCNAM!" >nul && (
rem echo FOUND
    )

echo PRCNAM : %PRCNAM%
echo PRCSPD : %PRCNAM:~-9,7%
echo.
```

Processor information is given as full sentence :

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

I want to extract the processor type such as "i7-6820HQ" in the middle of the string, maybe not always at the same position.

I succeed to extract processor's speed at the end of the string (there is also some garbage chars at the end, I had to use %PRCNAM:~-9,7% to get "2.70GHz"), but I'm unable to extract the processor type as "i7-6820HQ"... I made several trials with "find" and "findstr" like :

```
...set PRCNAM=%%a && echo %PRCNAM%| find "i" >nul...
...set PRCNAM=%%a && echo !PRCNAM!| findstr /r /c:"!PRCNAM!" >nul && (
   echo FOUND
   )
```

I search for "i" as start of processor information (that may not always be at the same position) but I don't know how to handle it further ?

Thank you for your help to solve this and explanations how to pick up a substring in wmi output in general, (avoid Powershell as I started with IBM computers and batch language in the 80s and I already have a set of ready batches...)

Comment: The simple and really always working solution for getting the full processor name as long as `wmic.exe` is installed at all – which is not the case anymore on fresh installations of Windows 11 22H2 – is the usage of `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CPU GET Name /VALUE 2^>nul') do for /F "delims=" %%H in ("%%G") do set "PRCNAM=%%H"`. The command  line used by you can already fail to get the entire string of the processor name.

Comment: I think your should first define what _"processor type"_ means for you. In my computer I get this: `AMD A9-9425 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G`. Is `A9-9425` the processor type in this case? Perhaps is the word in the name that have a dash... Note also that in my case there is not processor's speed at end.

Comment: @Aacini : I have indicated in my question, the processor type as "i7-6820HQ"...

Comment: Right! In _your computer_ the processor type is in the 3rd token and the speed at the 6th (`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz`). Why don't just do: `for /F "tokens=3,6" %%a in ("the line") do set "PRCNAM=%%a" & set "PRCSPD=%%b"`  ?

Comment: FYI, You do not need to use WMI to get that string, especially as WMIC.exe is relatively slow, and now deprecated. The simplest way is to go straight to the registry: ```@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0" /V "ProcessorNameString" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "PRCNAM=%%H"```.

Answer (score 1):

Just for info - there is not always an `i` in the name. On my system, I get

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU    X5650  @ 2.67GHz
```

That said, you can't split the name string by delimiters, because you don't have a reliable delimiter/token number. So you need a different method: get each "word" and look if it matches the pattern you search for  (`i[3579]-.*`), if yes - set the variable. (you can do the same for the speed). This does not work if the search pattern contains a space!

```
rem proc. info
setlocal 
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('wmic cpu get Name /format:csv') do (
  set PROC=%%a 
)
set "PROC=Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz" &REM for testing

set "prcnam=undetermined" &REM in case it isn't an 'i-something, like mine'
for %%a in (%PROC:)=^)%) do (
  echo %%a|findstr "^i[3579]-" >nul && set "prcnam=%%a"
  echo %%a|findstr "GHz$" >nul && set "prcspd=%%a"
)

echo PRCNAM : %PRCNAM%
echo PRCSPD : %PRCSPD%
```

Output for the test string from your system:

```
PRCNAM : i7-6820HQ
PRCSPD : 2.70GHz
```

Output on my system:

```
PRCNAM : undetermined
PRCSPD : 2.67GHz
```

It can be improved by looking at all possible (or better all relevant) Processor names and adapting the search pattern (or using more than one `findstr` per word)

**Edit** Aacini showed the output of an AMD processor (`AMD A9-9425 RADEON R5, 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G`), which does not contain the speed. You may want to change your code to `... get Name,MaxClockSpeed` (Note: it is a pure number in MHz (but without the unit, and `wmic` output is rounded)

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, that will help me a lot !
This is to extract basic information of laptops that are given to a non-profit organization, up to now no Xeon nor AMD but I'll have to consider these cases...